# Asp.net MVC - Asynch controller get functionality from my base controller

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, asynchronous, subclass, oop

I have a base controller which is subclassed from a standard mvc controller. This containers lots of useful methods specific to a Controller.

I now need to have some asych functionality in one of my new controllers

However, to do that you need to create a controller that subclasses AsyncController

But I also want to access functionality in my base controller

Obviously multiple inheritance isn't possible

so how do I get around this?

Answer (score 1):

You could externalize the functionality you are willing to reuse into a service layer, action filter, authorization filter, model binder, ... it will depend on the functionality you are willing to reuse so that you could easily switch the base controller to an async controller and still preserve the functionality. If you want to use async controllers you will need to derive from [AsyncController](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.asynccontroller.aspx).

Comment: let's say for the sake of argument I want all the functionality that is available in my base controller and that the base seems the right place for this functionality to exist. It seems an odd decision to force you to subclass a specific controller to make it asych. it forces brittle/repeated inheritance hierarchies - unless I am missing something. (Which is certainly not unheard of)

Comment: @josedelascasa, no you are not missing anything. It's the way the designers of the framework decided to implement this. There are some critics against the fact that they are using abstract classes instead of interfaces but that's the way it is and we cannot do much about it.

Answer (score 0):

You could make your controller class inherit `IAsyncManagerContainer` and `IAsyncController`, then implement this functionality yourself, perhaps using the code from MVC source code.  You could even encapsulate this in its own class that you delegate the functionality to.

Comment: yeah, that's not a bad idea. I was thinking about this the other way round - implementing Icontroller manually. but would be less work to do it your way round. thanks - will leave this question open for other suggestions for the moment though

Comment: but would still have to repeat this for each controller that needs asynch functionality though

Comment: @josedelascasa - That's why i suggested encapsulating the code in its own class, then delegating the calls.  You have to implement the methods for each controller manually, but that's just a matter of some boilerplate code.  You could even use code snippets to automate it.

Comment: ahh yes, gotcha. interested in hearing other approaches. seems like a pretty bad design flaw imho (the inheritance thing that is)

Comment: @josedelascasa - You could also create a base class that inherits from your base class that implements the Async interfaces.  Lack of multiple inheritence is generally considered a feature, because MI is very difficult to do correctly and adds a huge amount of complexity to the system.  Multiple interface inheritence is typicall sufficient.